# Java Задача : Отображение прямоугольного треугольника в консоли, с помощью цикла while

Tags: java, циклы, while

> ```
>     Здравствуйте, завис на задаче, не получается вывести треугольник в консоль с помощью цикла while;
>     
>     Вот что должно получиться: 
>     
>     #####    
>     ####     
>     ###      
>     ##       
>     # 
>     
>     Мой код:
> ```

```
        int n = 9;
        i = n; 

        while(i >= 1) {
            j = n;
            while(j <= i) {
                System.out.print(" " + '#');
                j++;
            }
            System.out.println("");
            j = 1;`введите сюда код`
            i--;
        }

        System.out.println("");
```

Comment: Надо писать не только что должно получиться, но и что сам получаешь в итоге, что неправильно по твоему мнению

Comment: Самое лучшее - это пройтись дебаггером и посмотреть что на каждой итерации у тебя получается и какая переменная какое значение принимает ↑↑↑   ..... это не считая того, что у тебя как минимум две синтаксических ошибки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка в инициализации счетчика строк. Сразу присваивается номер последней строки из n = 9, из-за этого и проблема:

```
    int n = 9;
    int i = n;
    while (i >= 1) {
        int j = 1;  // Ошибка!!! j = n;
        while (j <= i) {
            System.out.print(" #");
            j++;
        }

        System.out.println("");
        //j = 1; // избыточно 
        i--;
    }

    System.out.println("");
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогли разобраться)